# Find all comparision between "bytes" and "str"

Tags: python, python-2to3

I am migrating one big project from Python 2 -> Python 3, the issue with comparison  between "bytes" and "str" only found when the old code run into it and fail explicitly. If it falsely pass, i will not be aware.
One example:

```
def read_var_startaddr(self, var_name):
#__get_var_name() will return bytes
if self.__get_var_name() == var_name:
    print("do something")        
return self.__get_startaddr()
```

So i would like to fix this for the whole project, instead of waiting until something happens, there are twos things in my mind:

1. Use Notepad++: Search the whole project with regular expression, and checking by eyes ... to make sure no unexpected replacement happen.
   [Search with Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLvPL.png)
2. I would like the create wrapper the basic operator "==" or "!=", with a purpose to auto convert and compare corresponding values.

**My Question:**
With option 2, Is it possible to do wrap the basic operator, how to do it and what are the impacts it may cause?
Is there better way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps give [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/2to3.html) a try first (a tag you selected I assume unassumingly). It's built in with Python 3, and might save you a lot of time.

---

For number 2 specifically, you can overwrite the dunder method [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) in objects, and use that instead. Something like so:

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, bytes):
            self._item = item
        elif isinstance(item, str):
            self._item = bytes(item, 'utf-8')
        elif isinstance(item, int):
            self._item = bytes(str(item), 'utf-8')
        else:
            raise Exception("Item must be of type bytes, str, or int.")

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, bytes):
            return self._item == other
        elif isinstance(other, str):
            return self._item.decode("utf-8") == other
        elif isinstance(other, int):
            if self._item.isdigit():
                return int(self._item) == other
            else:
                raise Exception("Cannot compare non-int to int.")
```

Then all of the following would work:

```py
item = Item("hello")

item == "hello"  # True
item == b"hello" # True
```

```py
item = Item(100)

item == 100 # True
item == "100" # True
item == b"100" # True
```

Do note that all objects `Item` will now be comparable with respect to the new `__eq__` we wrote. If you are wondering "is there a way to modify *ALL* `==` comparison signs", the answer is... technically yes, but I promise you it is not worth it. You would have to deal with the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module and create some very confusing code.

---

You could also more simply create a function `compare_str_bytes()` that uses some of the code above to compare bytes and strings accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, with this i can use replacement to wrap around all my operands in all my comparison lines.

Answer (score 0):

One tool that would be able to do this more generally is the [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) type checker; that would be rather heavy-weight, but it would definitely find these issues.

It would probably find a lot of other issues, and it would generally be a major change to the program, so you'd have to evaluate it as a whole rather than specifically for this one issue.

Comment: Thanks, i will take it in consideration